# Convert XML File to Json object in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

all the xml files in the folder and select 1 xml file based on the condition and convert the XML file to json in spring boot.

Comment: Haven't you tried to do it yourself yet? You should write more detail about what problem you are facing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.